# Opacity of background in Textmate2

Tags: macos, textmatebundles, textmate2

I am new to Textmate 2. I have seen few people using textmate with a reduced opacity of the background color. I am trying to find a way to achieve that, but could not get to anything closer.

I tried tweaking the bundle file for the default theme, but eventually ended up messing the look of the existing theme.

What am I missing here. Do I need any other bundle to achieve it? How do I get a transparency in the background?

Comment: _"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"_ oh, hi close-voters. Are you **really** claiming that Textmate isn't a "tool used primarily for programming". Seriously? Are you on crack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah! yes I now get it!... I guess its different in Textmate2. All you need to do is to goto the bundle editor and change the value of background in settings.

For example if the value of background is #141414 then append the hex value of the desired transparency. For example you want the opacity to be 62.8% then you can change the value to be #141414A1.

0xA1 = 161

161/256 = 62.8%